# Loading data from existing connector table in JPA

Tags: jpa

I'm a beginner in JPA mapping. I have a simple entity (essentially a 2D matrix) specifying a value for every product group/cost group combination.

```
@Entity
public class CostDistribution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private ProductGroup productGroup;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private CostGroup costGroup;

    private Long value;
}
```

Now I'd like to get read-only access to the relevant column of this matrix when a ProductGroup is loaded (i.e. load all CostDistribution records where the product_group_id equals the id of the current product group). I cannot figure out how to do this. This is what I tried:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="cost_distribution", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_group_id"))
```

but I get an exception: `Same physical table name [cost_distribution] references several logical table names: [CostDistribution], [cost_distribution]`

What am I misunderstanding here?

```
@Entity
public class ProductGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max=50)
    private String name;

    @???
    private List<CostDistribution> costDistribution;
}
```

Comment: No idea what that mapping is supposed to mean. If this is a 1-N bidir (ProductGroup -CostDistribution) then it should be `@OneToMany`. You only use `@ElementCollection` when the element is not an entity. Any JPA doc should explain that

Comment: ProductGroup and CostGroup are simple tables, basically an ID and a name. CostDistribution maps a value to each combination of ProductGroup and CostGroup. It's structure is `product_group_id, cost_group_id, value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer to load the relevant data from the matrix:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="productGroup", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<CostDistribution> costDistribution;
```

This joins in the correct column from connector table. For example, when loading product group with id=1:

```
select productgro0_.id as id1_6_0_, productgro0_.name as name2_6_0_, ..., costdistri1_.value as value2_2_2_, 
from product_group productgro0_ 
left outer join cost_distribution costdistri1_ on productgro0_.id=costdistri1_.product_group_id 
left outer join cost_group costgroup2_ on costdistri1_.cost_group_id=costgroup2_.id where productgro0_.id=1
```